# Why does Apache airflow fail with the command: 'airflow initdb'?

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow

I am trying to install airflow on an AWS EC2 instance. The process seems to be pretty well documented by various sources on the web, however, I have run into a problem after I 'pip install' airflow; I get the below error when I execute the command 'airflow initdb':

```
[2019-09-25 13:22:02,329] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/bin/airflow", line 22, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 68, in <module>
    from airflow.www_rbac.app import cached_app as cached_app_rbac
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import AppBuilder
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api.manager import OpenApiManager
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Related, RelatedList
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .schema import TableSchemaOpts, ModelSchemaOpts, TableSchema, ModelSchema
  File "/home/cloud-user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 101
    class TableSchema(ma.Schema, metaclass=TableSchemaMeta):

                                      ^
```

my install steps are as follows:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install python-pip -y
pip install apache-airflow
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/.local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$AIRFLOW_HOME
cd $AIRFLOW_HOME
mkdir dags/
airflow initdb
airflow scheduler &
airflow webserver &
```

I have also tried installing Postgres, as per some of the instruction online:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y
```

or: `pip install apache-airflow[postgres]`

Not much is said about any configuration file changes that may be necessary.

While I am stuck on the initdb step, the ultimate goal is to have the database separated out into its own RDS instance.

I have also read some documentation that states that running airflow in a virtual environment is possible, but is this a requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` version has upgraded and it broke compatibility with py2 and py3.5 with 0.19.0

Run the following

```
pip install marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.17.1
```

and it should work.

Related issue on Airflow Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5430

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use k8s for deploy your app and go to Airflow 2.0 from Airflow 1.0 you can get same error and what you need to fix in deployment yaml:

**code in Deployment Airflow 1.0:**

```
<...>    
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: init
      image: <...>
      args:
        - initdb
<...>
```

**code in Deployment Airflow 2.0:**

```
<...>    
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: init
      image: <...>
      args: ["db", "init"]
<...>
```